# How is managed the queue in Laravel 6 in production environment?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have a Laravel 6 App running onto Elastic Beanstalk environment with a redis (Elastic Cache) base for jobs.

How the queue is launched in production ? In fact, I saw .ebextensions commands or Supervisor config, but it's seems that I have a php artisan queue:work running without doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using supervisord on production to start the queue-workers.
You can find an example of a queue- / php-worker [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration).

And you can read some official documentation specifically about using supervisor with laravel 6.x [here](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/tree/master/php-worker).